# Ways to store key-value pairs with optimized read, to be used along with a stream processing engine

Tags: apache-spark, redis, streaming, spark-streaming, rocksdb

We have data (static) with (approx.) `20M`rows and `50,000` columns. It's a sparse data, and we need fast read for a single cell value or a given column (all the rows for the column). Input is a streaming data, and we want to aggregate the input (last `x` mins) depending on the values from the DB (values mentioned above).

We need some suggestion on how should we proceed to have the lowest latency:

`1. We store the values in the Apache Spark in-memory (on-heap or off-heap) and also process the data using the same.
2. We store the values in Redis/RocksDB and process the data in Apache Spark.`

Apache Flink is out of consideration due to resistance in adding a new framework on to the stack, and we are looking for something more stable (as this problem is just a part of a project).

Answer (score 0):

With Flink, assuming you use the row id as the key, then you could store this data as state via a `Map<column id, cell value>`. Under the hood if you've configured Flink to use RocksDB as the state backend, then looking up a single cell is fast, as the key into RocksDB is the `<row id>` + `<column id>`.

You could also separately key by column, and iterate over all the rows, though that's obviously going to be slower - not sure what the definition of a "fast read" is for 1M rows of a given column.

With this approach you could then use Flink's support for [queryable state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html) to make the lookups very simple to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. By "fast read" for a given column, I meant that we are also considering the columnar store as the final result is dependent on all the values (static) in a column and each event in a stream contains key from row (so if we read a column for a required result then we also need to retrieve row keys to map event with specific static value), but as I mentioned it is a sparse data we are not sure of the type of store

Comment: As a POC I wanted to check out Apache Flink too but adding a framework on the stack for a feature doesn't seem to be the right option, plus the [queryable state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html) is in beta mode with no guarantees and possible breaking API changes.